# Drupal Contact Form with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, contact-form

I need to send my contact form via ajax and then show pop-up message.

For example if I'll send form POST data to some url it should response with "OK" or "FAIL"

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 6

A module is there for ajax submition

http://drupal.org/project/ajaxsubmit

```
$form['#ajaxsubmit'] = TRUE;
```

That will change your form behavior to ajax.

Drupal 7 core integrated it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what exactly I need to do. I have Drupal 6

Comment: your form need to appear in a popup? or you just submit form via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQuery Form plugin, it's very easy and practical to implement: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ajax module(http://drupal.org/project/ajax) to ajaxify your form, to show the popup, use a module like bettermessages, or growl or something of the sort.
Joshua